# AngularJS : Binding ngrepeat values to model in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-model

I am creating a simple FHIR client to edit patient data using AngularJS. I can't figure out why the values in the inputs are not bound to values in the object.

Naturally, I could cheat and implement `keyup` and `$scope.$apply()`, but something tells me this is not how it is supposed to be done in AngularJS.

I've tried using `$index` to bind the values directly to the values in the array, but that didn't seem to do anything.

Here is the code:

```
var app = angular.module('FhirClient', []);
app.controller('PatientCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

console.log("Evaluating Patient");
var responsePromise = $http.get("http://nprogram.azurewebsites.net/Patient/1?_format=json&_sm_au_=iMH046nNq52RDM6q");

responsePromise.success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log("Successful connection");
    $scope.patient = data;
});
responsePromise.error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    alert("AJAX failed!");
});

$scope.$watch('patient', function (newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log(newValue);
});

});
```

And the following HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="PatientCtrl">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Patient Details</h1>

        <code>{{patient | json}}</code>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h2>Names</h2>
            <div class="list-group" ng-repeat="names in patient.name track by $namesIndex">
                <h3><span class="label label-primary">{{x.use}}</span></h3>
                <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="lastName in names.family track by $familyNamesIndex">
                    <label for="familyName">Family Names:</label>
                    <input class="form-control" ng-model="lastName" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="firstName in names.given">
                    <label for="givenName">Given Names:</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="firstName"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the JSON:

```
{
"resourceType":"Patient",
    "text":
    {
        "status": "generated",
        "div": "<div xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'><p>Harley N Hobbs</p><p>16 Pier Road</p><p>STANWARDINE IN THE FIELDS</p><p>SY4 7IW</p><p>Date of birth: 1966-06-07</p></div>"
    },
    "identifier":
    [{
        "use": "official",
        "label": "SSN",
        "system": "http://hl7.org/fhir/sid/us-ssn",
        "value": "1"
    }],
    "name":
    [{
        "use": "official",
        "family":[ "Hobbs"],
        "given":[ "Harley"]
    }],
    "telecom":
    [{
        "system": "phone",
        "value": "077 8169 8899",
        "use": "home"
    }],
    "gender":
    {
        "coding":
        [{
            "system": "http://hl7.org/fhir/sid/v2-0001",
            "code": "male"
        }]
    },
    "birthDate": "1966-06-07",
    "deceasedBoolean": false,
    "address":
    [{
        "use": "home",
        "text": "16 Pier Road, STANWARDINE IN THE FIELDS, SY4 7IW",
        "line":[ "16 Pier Road"],
        "city": "STANWARDINE IN THE FIELDS",
        "zip": "SY4 7IW"
    }],
    "careProvider":
    [{
        "reference": "../organization/@1"
    }],
    "active": true

}
```

Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong here?

Here is a simplified JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gmpp2fyk/1/ . If you edit the textbox, JSON doesn't seem to be updated: `$watch` doesn't fire and the expression remains just the way it was.

Comment: show me your names JSON.

Comment: I am a little skeptic about your use of ng-repeat.

Comment: You have only one "name" in the json. Why do you want to do a ng-repeat over a single object?

Comment: In this particular case, there is only one name, however, names is an array and can contain more names and within this array you have an array of given names and family names

Comment: @DawidO it's seems fine to me

Comment: @RishiPrakash edited the question to clarify

Comment: My up vote for really nice question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the solution. Firstly, binding to the variable in `ng-repeat` didn't work because it (obviously) had a different scope. 
Secondly, the intuition to use index was right, but it was done in a wrong way:

Here is the working solution (https://jsfiddle.net/gmpp2fyk/15/):

```
<div ng-controller="PatientCtrl">
<div class="container">
    <h1>Patient Details</h1>
    {{patient | json}}
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <h2>Names</h2>
        <div class="list-group" ng-repeat="names in patient.name track by $index">
            <h3><span class="label label-primary">{{x.use}}</span></h3>
            <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="lastName in names.family track by $index">
                <label for="familyName">Family Names:</label>
                f:{{ $parent.$index }}
                <input class="form-control" ng-model="patient.name[$parent.$index].family[$index]" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="firstName in names.given track by $index">
                <label for="givenName">Given Names:</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="patient.name[$parent.$index].given[$index]" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6"></div>
</div>
```